# mixed versions of 28.0.0 and firebase 16.0.8 : ERROR

Tags: android, firebase

I have an error of mixed versions

1. android studio version of 3.3.1
2. Gradle of `4.10.1-all.zip`.

I am trying to insert firebase into my code but It is showing error regarding the mixed versions.

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`[over here it showing mixed versions]

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'`

Comment: What is the version error it is showing?

Comment: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... 
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

Comment: this was the error it is showing. I tried changing all the possible versions to be changed but did not get succeed. plz help

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Finally resolved it by excluding the support library from the firebase dependency.

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'){
    exclude group:'com.android.support'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **build.gradle** file at the bottom, add this code and sync gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DependencyResolveDetails : CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL error showed up

Comment: Is it not syncing?

Comment: Thank you it's working for me!!! I have removed DependencyResolveDetails and used only details -> .....